# copy french text from pdf file

Tags: pdf, text

I have a French thesis which I am trying to read, to better understand some parts I am trying to copy some text and use that in google translate, however if I copy text I am getting just rubbish as the pasted text. Most probably there is a problem with the encoding. And even more strangely, I can copy text from the first cover page of the document correctly which is also in French but from the rest, I am just getting a full of rubbish characters from the text that I pasted from the clipboard. Any ideas on how to read parts of this thesis?

Comment: Did you try `pdftotext`? It's in the package called `poppler-utils`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did not know this package but it is the same since the first page is read quite ok, and the other parts are not read correctly... A lot of crap characters...

Comment: So show us a snippet with the strange characters.

Comment: Laboratoire de M´canique des Sols, Structures et Mat´riaux - CNRS U.M.R. 8579
e
e

^L^L"

s^XA` ' ^XA` 6 W Q % X ^X "P ' ^X W " "i Q 
<91>(a<83>$^?I"y&%9^X^Q"IQ<98>(aF$^X9W&W7^X(#A<85>

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.ecp.fr/files/content/sites/mssmat/files/Personnel/bendhiah/THESE_arlequin_web.pdf) the pdf involved ?

I tried a few things, like changing encoding, convert and re-encode, but i think you are in the situation described [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-change-the-text-encoding-of-a-PDF-document) :

> your best bet is to save the PDF as a images (TIFF or PNG) and then
>   combine them back together and OCR.